# How to reset MySQL Installer to a default start

Tags: mysql, sql, installation, mysql-connector

This question may have many forms, but for me I want the wizard to display the default installer menu as the first time you install MySQL

My installer keeps showing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd17d.png) menu, instead of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxy6O.png) which is shown in the tutorial videos I see

One issue to address is that I have tried to install MySQL once before and for some reason I was just stuck in the middle of installation and didn't get to end it. Therefore it may seem that this caused the issue I am currently experiencing

To try solve the problem I tried to uninstall it on the Programs and Features there are [two programs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s44eJ.png) the MySQL Installer - Community and the My SQL Connector Net 8.0.19.

I can easily uninstall the MySQL Installer - Community but the Connecter doesn't seem to be uninstalled. I also tried to delete the remaining files that may be left on the computer

Also, I have not found these folders,
C:\Program Files\MySQL
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL
C:\ProgramData\MySQL
C:\Users[User-Name]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL
I may have deleted them also before, I have seen in another forum to try to delete these folders, but no luck.

I hope there will be a solution for this or even an alternative so that I can use MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have residual files on "Program Files" or the instalation folder, i had a similar problem and i fixed it this way

Comment: i deleted these three folders C:\Program Files\MySQL, C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL, C:\ProgramData\MySQL, or is there a separate folder i need to check to remove the residual files

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-troubleshooting.html try this, idk if it will work but it seems a similar problem, if the trouble persist try with a manual instalation: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-mysql/